# WSO2 EMM: Every time creates a new VPN

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

WSO2 EMM Version: 2.0.1

Database: MySQL

I am setting VPN on iOS device using https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Setting+Up+a+VPN+on+iOS+Devices+via+the+REST+API API.

But every time I call an API, WSO2EMM is creating a new VPN. I just want to update an existing VPN connection or remove the VPN connection if an update is not possible.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Could you go to the EMM console and under policy create a new policy and in this policy define VPN configurations?

Comment: EMM Console doesn't haven configuration for VPN. I am on 2.0.1. I haven't checked newer versions.

Comment: I think you are talking about 2.1.0 release. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/iOS+Device#iOSDevice-iOSconfigurationsforWSO2EMM

Comment: Created a bug in wso2 https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-1484.